# Search selected checkbox values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a dropdown with checkbox list. When I select items and try to display in the grid by clicking the search button, I'm not able to do that.

```
protected void btnSearchEmpCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedValues = string.Empty;
        foreach (ListItem item in cblEmpCode.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
                selectedValues += "'" + item.Value + "',";
        }
        if (selectedValues != string.Empty)
            selectedValues = selectedValues.Remove(selectedValues.Length - 1);
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT *FROM Details WHERE Emp_Code IN (" + selectedValues + ")", con);
        SqlDataAdapter Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        Adpt.Fill(dt);
        AIGrids.DataSource = dt;
        AIGrids.DataBind();
    }
```

Can anyone correct me if I have went wrong somewhere.

Comment: do not write your SqlCommand like that, Google SqlParameters

Comment: Your code has SQL injection

Comment: @RomanPushkin how can be SQL injection be there if selected values are from checkbox?

Comment: by changing the value of the checkbox

Comment: @ScottSelby: how is it possible for the visitor to change the value of the checkbox? i don't think it is possible IMO.

Comment: @ScottSelby then assignment of those values is in the hands of programmer...why programmer will himself assign ";drop table table_name" to checkbox

Comment: @F.R.I.E.N.D.S. I don't know how your values are stored and where they come from. If they come from database, and in the database they're come from some kind of UI, it's possible to execute sql code. Someone can change this logic in the future. And they won't be responsible for that, because SQL injection is in _your_ code. Now it's not vulnerable, but it is potentially vulnerable and dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

First thing:

make sure that there is gap between `*From` in

```
"SELECT *FROM Details WHERE Emp_Code IN (" + selectedValues + ")"
```

second make sure that query is not forming as:

```
"SELECT *FROM Details WHERE Emp_Code IN (val1,val2,)"
```

(with comma remaining at last.)

**It should form like:**

```
"SELECT *FROM Details WHERE Emp_Code IN (val1,val2)"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1:**  you are adding single quotes `'` to `Emp_Code` column .
**Problem 2:**  you are not giving `space` between `*` and `FROM`

Try This:

```
protected void btnSearchEmpCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValues = string.Empty;
    foreach (ListItem item in cblEmpCode.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
            selectedValues +=  item.Value + ",";
    }

    if (selectedValues != string.Empty)
        selectedValues = selectedValues.Remove(selectedValues.Length - 1);
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Details WHERE Emp_Code IN (" + selectedValues + ")", con);
    SqlDataAdapter Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    Adpt.Fill(dt);
    AIGrids.DataSource = dt;
    AIGrids.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: how can be sql injection attack be there if selected value is from checkbox?

Comment: Instead of passing 'selected values' in the query, if someone passes any harmful sql into the event source/sender, your db is gone.

Comment: @codebrain but passing selected values or anything is job of programmer...sql injection is nothing to do with it...we have to just take care of what values may get assigned to selectedvalues variable...and in this case it does not seems any harmful since directly assigning through checkbox

Comment: yeah, i get it. but what i wanted to say is instead of passing "SelectedValues" directly into an sql query, using sqlParameter will take care of injection attacks. :) you dont need to do anything else much

Comment: @F.R.I.E.N.D.S. you don't seem to understand injection attacks

Comment: @ScottSelby may be :(

Comment: When I select the checkbox items and hit search, I get this error message. DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Column Name'. I checked and I have named the column name the same everywhere.

Comment: @F.R.I.E.N.D.S. - this looks like a  web forms website, and user can edit the HTML to make the value of the Checkbox = "'); DROPTABLE User...'"